# Reutilizing components on React

Tags: reactjs, href, reusability

I'm working with React and i'm trying to reuse some code because i have to put a button on every page; so i declared it as a function on another component and i'm trying to call it on one of my pages, but i'm getting an error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

I have the component:

```
    export const whatsappLink = () => {
      return (
        <a
          href=""
          className="link-simulator floating"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <i className="fab fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
        </a>
      );

};
```

And i'm call in it like this on my render:

```
<div>{whatsappLink}</div>
```

Why am i getting this error? And how should i call it?

Comment: The components are used this way `<whatsappLink />`

Comment: I tried that, but i get this errors: whatsappLink /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements. And also this: The tag <whatsappLink> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `JSX` tag syntax to render the functional component, also the name should be PascalCased i.e first letter should be uppercased. Trying to render a component like `{whatsappLink}` will cause an error because functions can not be valid React children.

```
// when trying to render the WhatsappLink component
<div>
  <WhatsappLink/>
</div>
```

```
// define WhatsappLink component
export const WhatsappLink = () => {
   return (
     <a
       href=""
       className="link-simulator floating"
       target="_blank"
     >
       <i className="fab fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
     </a>
   );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods of rendering your "what's app link": as a react functional component, or a function that returns a JSX.Element.

Let's assume you have a parent component called "App" that wants to render the what's app link. That function, for sake of simplicity, will look like this:

```js
function App() { 
 return (
  <div>
    {/* whats app link */}
  </div>
 )
}
```

**React Functional Component**

Create a functional component called `WhatsAppLink`. All react components use the PascalCase naming convention. The only update to make this change is the function name:

```js
export const WhatsAppLink = () => { 
 return (
        <a
          href=""
          className="link-simulator floating"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <i className="fab fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
        </a>
      );
}
```

You could also use the function expression syntax:

```js
function WhatsAppLink(){ 
 return (
  {/* your return html */}
 )
}

export default WhatsAppLink
```

To render that in you `App` simply use JSX:

```js
function App() { 
 return (
  <div>
    <WhatsAppLink />
  </div>
 )
}
```

**Function that Returns JSX Element**

This is most likely what you were originally going for. Simply create a function within your "App" component and invoke it in the JSX to return the element.

Your "App" component would look like:

```js
function App() { 
 const renderWhatsAppLink = () => { 
  // you can call this function whatever you like
  // the naming convention is camelCase 
  return (
   <a
          href=""
          className="link-simulator floating"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <i className="fab fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
        </a>
  )
 }

 return (
  <div>
   {renderWhatsAppLink()} // remember to invoke the function to access the return
  </div>

 )
}
```

**React Functional Component vs. Function that Returns JSX**

The benefit of using the React Functional Component is that you can pass data to that component called `props`. If you really aim to reuse this component you could pass something like `hrefLink` as a prop and access that in the component. You can even pass children, functions, etc. to the component.

Use the Function that Returns JSX only when you know it will not be used anywhere else in the application. When you start using that function three times, may be time to convert it to a React Functional Component.

**Notes on JSX**

JSX allows you to use Javascript in HTML with the use of `{ }` curly braces. If you pass a function in there like you did `{whatsAppLink}` nothing will happen because you are not invoking the function.